# NSDate formating from UTC to AEST format with daylight Saving

Tags: objective-c, iphone, nsdateformatter

Hi I am trying to format UTC Date that I receive as yyyyMMddHHmmss to EST Australian Brisbane date format but I keep getting 1 Hr behind.

I am using the following function to **convert local date** entered to **UTC date** time:

```
+(NSString *)getUTCFormatedDateString:(NSString *)localDate
{
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
  NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
  [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
  NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[self getDateFromString:localDate]];
  return dateString;
}
```

When I enter the following date : **03-Feb-2015 4:25 pm**

I get **20150204062510** this as UTCFormatted Date.

Now when I try to convert this date string back to local date time  using the following function to **convert UTC date back to local date** (i.e. Australia/Brisbane):

```
+(NSString *)getESTFormatedDateStringFomUTCFormatedDateString:(NSString *)UTCdate
{   
  NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];d
  NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"EST"];
  [dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
  [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy h:mm a"];

  NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[self getDateFromString:UTCdate]];

  return dateString;
}
```

I get : **03-Feb-2015 3:25 pm**

However the output should be **03-Feb-2015 4:25 pm**

I have tried as per suggestions here [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"AEST"] or [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"Australia/Brisbane"] then I get **04-Feb-2015 6:25 am**

Thank you again.

Comment: Please provide the `UTCdate`, output you are getting and the code that displays the incorrect date. In other words  complete test code. Also please clarify "EST", is this USA EST as in New York? If you want the Australian Brisbane timezone it is: "AEST"

Answer (score 0):

I would expect `EST` to mean "Eastern Standard Time" in the US, based on this entry in the dictionary returned by `+[NSTimeZone abbreviationDictionary]`: `EST = "America/New_York";`.

Try using `Australia/Brisbane` as the name (or finding something more appropriate in `+[NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]`)